# How to write $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = s \mid X_2 = s )$ using c.d.f.s of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2 : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

How to write $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = s \mid X_2 = s )$ using c.d.f.s of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

I can get

$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = s \mid X_2 = s)$
$= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 = s \cap X_2 = s)}{\mathbb{P}(X_2 = s)}$

But is here anything that I can express as c.d.f.s?

Comment: Not unless $X_1, X_2$ are *discretely distributed* (integer valued) random variables.

Comment: @GrahamKemp They are.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, X_2$ are discrete random variables then

$\begin{align}\Bbb P(X_1{=}s\mid X_2{=}s) & =\dfrac{\Bbb P(X_1{=}s, X_2{=}s)}{\Bbb P(X_2{=}s)} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\Bbb P(X_1{=}s, X_2{\leq}s)-\Bbb P(X_1{=}s, X_2{<}s)}{\Bbb P(X_2{\leq}s)-\Bbb P(X_2{<}s)}
\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\Bbb P(X_1{\leq}s{,}X_2{\leq}s){-}\Bbb P(X_1{<} s{,}X_2{\leq} s){-}\Bbb P(X_1{\leq}s{,}X_2{<}s){+}\Bbb P(X_1{<}s{,}X_2{<}s)}{\Bbb P(X_2{\leq}s){-}\Bbb P(X_2{<}s)} \end{align}$

If they are integer-valued random variables, where $F_{1,2}(,)$ is the joint CDF of $X_1,X_2$, and $F_2()$ is the CDF of $X_2$, then :$$\begin{align}\Bbb P(X_1{=}s\mid X_2{=}s) &=\dfrac{F_{1,2}(s,s)-F_{1,2}(s-1,s)-F_{1,2}(s,s-1)+F_{1,2}(s-1,s-1)}{F_2(s)-F_2(s-1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: And why is this?

Comment: Do you see why $~\Bbb P(X_2=s)~=~\Bbb P(X_2\leq s)-\Bbb P(X_2<s)~$ ?  Then also $~\Bbb P(X_1=s, X_2=s) ~=~ \Bbb P(X_1\leq s, X_2=s)-\Bbb P(X_1<s, X_2=s)~$ and so on.

Comment: Okay I see now.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions:

1. Are X1 and X2 discrete?
2. Are X1 and X2 independent?

If the answer to Q1 is no, then the answer is zero/not defined.
If the answer to Q2 is no, then the joint probability cannot be separated

The answer

$= \frac{(F_{X_1}(s)-F_{X_1}(s-1))(F_{X_2}(s)-F_{X_2}(s-1))}{F_{X_2}(s)-F_{X_2}(s-1)}$